# Partitioning (unmounted) HD not allowed: "only one primary partition allowed"

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Having one extra HD (unmounted) that I wish to partition, GParted won't allow me to select "New".

[image: resizing]

[image: cannot create more than 1 primary partition]

The drive is unmounted.

I am using another HD for my OS. This HD I wish to partition is merely an extra drive for storage, and in the future may hold other OS-es.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something is wrong... your 35 pic shows sdb (a device) where I'd expect a partition name (sdb1 for example).   If the disk were mine, I'd delete everything and start again, especially if this disk was new (eg. you shrunk a partition for example on a factory formatted drive as whoever first created the drive used a non-standard program I suspect).  I've seen this on purchased drives, where a 'delete-all-parts&&start-again' fixes the issue (I've never explored why sorry)

Comment: Thanks @guiverc. I've actually never used the drive until today, I installed it in my PC a couple of weeks ago while building, but have only today (using "Disks") formatted it into EXT4 and mounted it. I made some folders but nothing exciting. I have not yet done any partitioning. The printscreen doesn't show it, but I then cancel the process (as I'm not sure what the effects will be).

Comment: to close voters -- he is obviously using ubuntu, and ubuntu allows formating a device without a partition table. True it is an unusual occurrence but not off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you formated a device without a partition table. Thus there can only be one primary "partition".

To fix it you need to make a partition table, either MBR or GPT, then make partitions. Of course backup any data you need as the current device table will be erased.

Comment: Thanks, I created a partition table  (GPT)  using GParted, and could proceed as planned, partitioning the disk. Both only could be primary partitions, so I left that option as is. 
Everything seems to work, thanks both for the help!

Comment: GPT only has primary partitions. Since it is designed to accommodate a very large number of partitions, extended partitions are unnecessary and not supported.